# what is the main diffrence between whitebox testing and Automation testing?

Tags: testing

Some point of view both are same technique. But i am confused with both technique so i want specific difference which will help me to understand the meaning of both technique...
Thanks in advance

Comment: please dont ask this type of questions use google for this or your text book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White box testing is a method of testing software wherein one looks at the internals of the system rather than just the front-end functionality, so for example running unit tests. White box testing can be manual or automated.

Automated testing is testing using tools that run the tests or part of the tests automatically (without interference from the tester). Automated testing can be white box or black box.

So there isn't any similarity as far as I can see, they certainly are not the same technique. For more details see Wikipedia.

Comment: As an aside I learned today that lmgtfy links are banned here.

Answer (score 0):

White-box testing is a method of testing software that tests internal structures or workings of an application, as opposed to its functionality (i.e. black-box testing). In white-box testing an internal perspective of the system, as well as programming skills, are used to design test cases. 

Automation testing is nothing but testing an application 
with the help of a tool which could perform all the actions 
with least or no manual intervention,verification and 
reporting the results.

U could have googled this. Never prefer SO for asking such questions.